# Create & Join Channel Error for Hyperledger Fabric WARN 001 Failed Loading ClientOU certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was following the hyperledger fabric documentation. but im stuck here without knowing what to do.Please help
I ran the code

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c ehr -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/sr
```

c/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.
example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

And I got an error like this

> WARN 001 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: invalid argument]

This error comes from AdminOU, PeerOU and OrdererOU certificates as well